# What is the second type argument to ForeignKey in the django stubs typehints?

Tags: python-3.x, django, type-hinting, python-typing, pylance

What should I put in the place of the **`_GT`** type variable in this snippet?

```py
from django.db.models import ForeignKey, PROTECT

order = ForeignKey["ExtensionOrder", _GT](
    "subscriptions.ExtensionOrder",
    null=False,
    on_delete=PROTECT
)
```

The stub is here: ([source](https://github.com/typeddjango/django-stubs/blob/1.14.0/django-stubs/db/models/fields/related.pyi#L107))

```py
class ForeignKey(ForeignObject[_ST, _GT]):
    _pyi_private_set_type: Union[Any, Combinable]
    _pyi_private_get_type: Any

    ...
    
    # class access
    @overload  # type: ignore
    def __get__(self, instance: None, owner) -> ForwardManyToOneDescriptor: ...
    # Model instance access
    @overload
    def __get__(self, instance: Model, owner) -> **_GT**: ...
    # non-Model instances
    @overload
    def __get__(self: _F, instance, owner) -> _F: ...
```

Pylance is griping about it, but I'm not sure what **`_GT`** should be

Comment: `django-stubs` was developed to work with shipped `mypy` plugin, it doesn't support pylance and explicit annotations won't help resolve most of the arising issues (I participated in its development). This `_GT` is filled by the plugin. However, if you're interested exactly in `_GT` for fields and don't expect other type checking to work properly without plugin, read the docstring [here](https://github.com/typeddjango/django-stubs/blob/1.14.0/django-stubs/db/models/fields/__init__.pyi#L48) - it applies to almost all Field subclasses.

Comment: `_GT` in your case should be `ExtensionOrder` too, AFAIC, `ForeignKey` is a symmetric descriptor.

Comment: django-types is the way to go for non mypy type checkers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a `Union` with the `Combinable` class.
It can't be imported at run-time though so nest it in a `TYPE_CHECKING` check.

```py
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING, Union
from django.db.models import ForeignKey, PROTECT
if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from django.db.models import Combinable

order = ForeignKey[Union["ExtensionOrder" , "Combinable"], "ExtensionOrder"](
    "subscriptions.ExtensionOrder",
    null=False,
    on_delete=PROTECT
)
```